# Need advice on purchasing flashes for use with a light tent

Tags: equipment-recommendation, flash, studio-lighting

I am looking to purchase three flashes for use with a light tent and am unsure of which I should purchase. I found the following on Amazon, both of which look really good and have great reviews, but I'm not sure which I should get. Here are links to them:

- [Yongnuo YN-560 Speedlight Flash for Canon and Nikon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004GZLFHM)
- [Yongnuo YN-560 II Speedlight Flash for Canon and Nikon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0079M711S)

Which of those do you think would be better? Or, if you have an alternative that is in the same price range, feel free to let me know about it.

Thanks for your advice

Comment: I'm sure the Mark II has extra features, but for what you're doing, you will find that almost any flash will give good results.  What will affect the images more is where you place the lights and how you compose the shot.

Answer (score 2):

The Yongnuo flashes are good value for money. I've used the 460's - they're inexpensive and work well (I've used them in manual mode with wireless triggers).

For a light tent, doing product shots of non-moving things, I'd find it much simpler to use a tripod and some inexpensive fixed lights.  But if you want to use flash, as AJ said, you don't need a lot of power, so most any flash will do as long as you have a way of triggering it off-camera (optical slave built in, sync cord or wireless trigger)